# How do you concatenate a session variable string with another string

Tags: java, jsp, struts

So say I have the following in my properties file:

```
property_one = "you ran 5 miles today"
```

Currently my jsp file displays this property

I would like to substitute out the `5` and make it dynamic. So assume I have a variable holding this value in the session.

In my JSP file, how would I do the concatenation?

My plan is to alter my properties file:

```
property_one = "you ran"
property_two = "miles today"
```

However I don't know how to concatenate these with a session variable.

EDIT: current code

```
<c:set var="runMessage"><bean:message bundle="RUN_MESSAGE" key="property_one"/>
```

Comment: What's the JSP code you're currently using to display `property_one`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Struts 1 you use bean message tag to read from the ResourceBundle. If you want to have a dynamic message you put placeholders. Example:

mymessages.properties

> property_one = "you ran {0} miles today"

And then in the JSP you do this:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean"%>
<bean:message key="property_one" arg0="${sessionScope.miles}"/>
```

Comment: ahh I like this...I'll try it out.